# Controlling Access to crontab from others users

Tags: cron

I try to Controlling Access to crontab from other user, example:

usre 1 is userDemo1 with crontab and second user userDemo2, I need to list crontab of userDemo1 from userDemo2 but I get error "must be privileged to use -u".

What grant or permission needs to userDemo2 ?

best regards
Mexman

Create the /etc/cron. d/cron. allow file but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [the source code](https://github.com/systemd-cron/crontab/blob/master/crontab.c#L202), it seems like you need root privilege to use `-u` flag on another user.

```c
while (EOF != (argch = getopt(argc, argv, getoptarg))) {
    switch (argch) {
    // ...
    case 'u':
        // ...
        if ((getuid() != ROOT_UID) &&
            (getuid() != pw->pw_uid))
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                "must be privileged to use -u\n");
            exit(ERROR_EXIT);
        }
        // ...
```

So, simply execute the command with `sudo`, like `sudo crontab -u userDemo2`.
Note that you should add user1 into sudoers file beforehand by `sudo usermod -aG sudo userDemo1`.